# Symfony 2 Injecting logger service

Tags: symfony, logging, service, monolog

I got a strange problem using the logger service in symfony 2:

When injecting the logger to a service, I get a type error because LoggerInterface expected but Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger given.

Also if I try to inject a custom logger, I get error because of undefined service.

Here is my code:

confiy.yml

```
monolog:
channels: ['payment']
handlers:
    paymentlog:
        type: stream
        path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/payment.log"
        level: debug
        channels: [payment]
```

service.yml

```
#payment_services
  payment.gateway_payments:
    class: AppBundle\Service\paymentService
    arguments: ["@service_container", "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@logger"]
```

Service:

```
<?php

  namespace AppBundle\Service;

  use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface;

  class paymentService {

    private $container;
    private $em;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, EntityManager $em, LoggerInterface $logger){
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

Also injecting the logger with @monolog.logger.paymentlog is giving me an error "undefinded service"

Can someone please tell me where I am wrong?

THX a lot.

Comment: What do you want? Are you want custom logger for payment.log?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#dic-tags-monolog). Also: [This](http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html#using-a-logger-inside-a-service).

Comment: @ccKep: Thank you for this hint, after fixing the problem with my namespace this did the trick. And Yes I wanted to have a custom logger for payment log, but couldn't use a seperate channel for it, since it would give me errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
use Monolog\Logger;
```

instead of this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface;
```

And after this;

```
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, EntityManager $em, Logger $logger){
```

insetad of this:

```
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, EntityManager $em, LoggerInterface $logger){
```

Comment: Close but no cigar.  Still want to typehint aganst LoggerInterface.  They just need to use the correct namespace.  They copy/pasted an old piece of code.

Comment: Yes maybe you are right @Cerad I haven't thought about the IDE is generating the wrong use statement.

Comment: I mean normally yes unless the OP is on an earlier Symfony version

Comment: If they were using an old enough version then they would not have had the problem in the first place.  And no, the namespace you posted is not correct.

Comment: Woops I don't know where the 7 came from... `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`

Comment: Thank you very much @Cerad and Jason Roman. With your help now everything works fine. Reading the doc I did not see the use-Statement so I did a wild guess. Feel stupid now...